# Finding the source of the JSON data used for a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json, developer-tools

The webpage in question is https://www.rolimons.com/deals. Note that I have permission from the developer for this.

The page displays a list of items (which refresh about every five seconds) and the most likely answer is that they're retrieved from a JSON file.

Using Chrome's developer tools on the network tab, I identified that the webpage makes requests to two scripts on the site: https://www.rolimons.com/js/deals.js and  https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity

The latter request is repeated about every 5 seconds and I presume the data must come from this. However, the JSON data from it does not match up to the data on the webpage.

How can I find out where the data from the items on the page originates from?

Comment: Data can only be there in 4 places: 1) In HTML tags, 2) inline scripts, 3) .js files 4) any URLs called in the network tab. Just make sure "All" is selected so that you don't miss any of the types of calls.

Comment: Also, localStorage. (But it should have been placed in storage by first 4 anyway)

Comment: It's probably coming from `activity`. The values that are shown may be the result of calculations made from that raw data, so you can't see the correspondence easily.

Comment: Most probably there are arrays of data loaded in the initial page (by PHP or JSP) and then the IDs are coming from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the URL:
https://www.rolimons.com/deals

This is the variable:
item_details

Try refreshing the site after going to the deals page.

Item details, etc. are loaded in the initial page rendering.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah I see! Is there any way of knowing where `item_details` is loaded from or would that be PHP? Also, that data is filtered before it is displayed (as not all those items are shown). Is there a JSON file which displays the filtered data (and a seperate JSON file for the variable `item_details`?)

Comment: Could be any server language like PHP or JSP or Node. Also, you may have to  read through lot of the JS code to figure it out.